# Screen no exists for Python's Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm learning Kivy but when I want to load the new screen it tells me that it doesn't exist.

edited : [ how to work with `screen` in kivy correctly ]

Error :

```
raise ScreenManagerException('No Screen with name "%s".' % name)
 kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "startup_screen".
```

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
from startup_screen import StartupScreen

class MyApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (300, 500)
        sm = ScreenManager()
        self.title = "App Test"
        return sm

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.current = "startup_screen"

MyApp().run()
```

startup_screen.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """
<StartupScreen>
    name: 'startup_screen'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (.93, .93, .93)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
   
    Image:
        id: img_logo
        source: "resources/img/logo.png"
        size_hint: (.8,.8)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
"""

class StartupScreen(Screen):

    Builder.load_string(kv)

    def __init__(self):
        super(StartupScreen, self).__init__()

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        from kivy.clock import Clock

        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.load_navigation(), 5)
    
    @staticmethod
    def load_navigation():
        from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

        app = MDApp.get_running_app()
        app.theme_cls = ThemeManager()
        app.theme_cls.primary_hue = "600"
        app.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Teal"
        app.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        
        from navigation import NavigationScreen
        app.root.current = "navigation"
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your code is that you are not creating a `StartupScreen`. Your `kv` string defines a rule for how a `StartupScreen` should be built, but it does not build one. A simple fix is to just add a line in your `build()` method to create the `StartupScreen`:

```
def build(self):
    Window.size = (300, 500)
    sm = ScreenManager()
    sm.add_widget(StartupScreen())  # createe the StartupScreen
    self.title = "App Test"
    return sm
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo! Thanks bro!